# Response too large to be displayed

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, I have been experiencing "Response too large to be displayed. Size: 340188 > Max: 204800" error in the response data in often. Though I have tried to update the "View.Result.Tree.Max size as 0. But again facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you try to use http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file ?

Answer (score 10):

In user.properties file add this:

> view.results.tree.max_size=0

Case is important, and '_' not '.' in max_size

Restart jmeter

That's it

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous

> Maximum size (in bytes) of HTML page that can be displayed.
>   Set to zero to disable the size check and display the whole response.
>   Defaults to: 10485760

Comment: I have tried this. Jmeter.properties file shows view.results.tree.max_size=0 in default. but I have changed as you said, "view.results.tree.maxsize=0". Again I am getting the same error :(

Comment: Put it in user.properties and ensure you remove the leading # character. Also don't change the syntax with_ . Otherwise your option is to put a very high value in it.

Answer (score 2):

Open jmeter.properties file from bin folder.

Find view.results.tree.max_size and update it as below.

```
view.results.tree.max_size=0
```

[image]

**Restart Jmeter**

Answer (score -2):

Open `jmeter.properties` file from bin folder

1. Maximum size of HTML page that can be displayed; `default=200 * 1024`
2. Set it to 0 to disable the size check and display the whole response
3. Look for `view.results.tree.max_size=204800`

So you have to set it to be 0

```
view.results.tree.max_size=0
```